# Verification of $\frac{d}{dt}(\hat{v}\cdot\hat{v})=0$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

I would like to verify if the following is actually true:

$$\frac{d}{dt}(\hat{v}\cdot\hat{v}) = \frac{d}{dt}\left|\left|\hat{v}\right|\right|^2 = 0$$

My thought on this is that since $\hat{v}$ is a unit vector of a velocity vector, $\left|\left|\hat{v}\right|\right|$ is always 1 and thus its derivative is going to be 0.

This is in contrast to

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left|\left|\vec{v}\right|\right|^2 = \vec{a}\cdot\vec{v} + \vec{v}\cdot\vec{a}$$

as $\vec{v}$ is not a unit vector.

Is this a valid thought process?

Thank you for your time,

Eric

Comment: Yes, this is true for any differentiable parameterized curve ${\bf r}(t)$ for which ${\bf r}$ has unit length.

Comment: Thanks! Is it that way as the magnitude is always one or is there are more 'complicated' reason?

Comment: what do you mean by a unit vector of a velocity vector? do you mean the direction vector of the velocity?

Comment: @abel Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: No, that's all, and in fact, you proved just that in your display equation above (just replace $\hat{v}$ with ${\bf r}(t)$)! Note if ${\bf r}(t)$ describes the position of an object, then $||{\bf r}(t)|| \equiv 1$ means that the object is moving around on the unit sphere, and your identity gives that ${\bf r}(t)' \cdot {\bf r}(t) = 0$, which recovers a description of the tangent plane to the sphere at any point.